# how to calculate percentage of individual field in MongoDB using aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions, nosql-aggregation

I want to calculate the percentage of the position of a football player field-wise to the country they belong to.
Let's say, there are a total 800 players from Nepal whereas only 20 were goal keepers so percentage would be Nepal: 2.5 %

My Dataset

```
[{
"position":"defenser",
"country":"Nepal"
},
{
"position":"defenser",
"country":"Nepal"
},
{
"position":"goal keeper",
"country":"Nepal"
},
{
"position":"goal keeper",
"country":"France"
},
{
"position":"defenser",
"country":"France"
},
{
"position":"goal keeper",
"country":"France"
},
{
"position":"defenser",
"country":"France"
},
{
"position":"defenser",
"country":"Nepal"
}
]
```

there are 3 defenser from Nepal out of total 4 and 2 defenser from france out of 4.

Expected output
:

```
{"country":"Nepal", "position": "defenser", "percentage":"75"}
{"country":"France", "position": "defenser", "percentage":"50"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query

- group by country and position, and count
- group by country, to calculate the totalSum for that country
- map dividing the count/totalSum and * 100
- unwind and replace root
- result is, for each country the percentage each position takes

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62edb35578a49d8782851477)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": {"country": "$country", "position": "$position"},
    "sum": {"$sum": 1}}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": "$_id.country",
    "players": {"$push": "$$ROOT"},
    "totalsum": {"$sum": "$sum"}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"players": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$players",
        "in": 
         {"position": "$$this._id.position",
          "country": "$_id",
          "percentage": 
           {"$multiply": 
             [{"$divide": ["$$this.sum", "$totalsum"]}, 100]}}}}}},
 {"$unwind": "$players"}, {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$players"}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as this data set and the problem is concerned we can get the appropriate result without using $$ROOT and $replaceRoot functions too.

**Solution:**

1. Group country-wise and get the total and push the position
2. Then unwind the array of position

3  Then multiple groups of country and positions and there individual
sum.

4  In last project stage calculate the percentage

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
 $group: {
  _id: '$country',
  sum: {
   $sum: 1
  },
  position: {
   $push: '$position'
  }
 }
}, {
 $project: {
  _id: 0,
  country: '$_id',
  sum: 1,
  position: 1
 }
}, {
 $unwind: {
  path: '$position'
 }
}, {
 $group: {
  _id: {
   position: '$position',
   country: '$country'
  },
  individualSum: {
   $sum: 1
  },
  sum: {
   $first: '$sum'
  }
 }
}, {
 $project: {
  _id: 0,
  position: '$_id.position',
  country: '$_id.country',
  individualSum: 1,
  sum: 1,
  percentage: {
   $multiply: [
    {
     $divide: [
      '$individualSum',
      '$sum'
     ]
    },
    100
   ]
  }
 }
}])
```